# Directive that manually copies HTML content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a custom directive that will replace itself with the template and also copy the `text()` over to the replaced version.

Why not use `ng-transclude`? Well, it's an overkill, given there's no HTML inside the directive, just text that I want to copy over. It also creates another HTML element, which is a bit of a waste.

The problem is that where there is a template, Angular will pass the template as `$element` and there is no way that I know of to access the original content. Bindings won't work either because the value is not inside an attribute but the element's content.

Directive:

```
angular.module('ui', [])
.directive('foo', 
    function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
          replace: true,
          template: '<p>Insert here</p>',
          compile: function(element, attrs) {
              console.log('compile time text: ' + element.text());
              return function($scope, element, attrs) {
                  console.log('link time text: ' + element.text());
              };
          }
      }
    });
```

Usage:

```
<div ng-app="ui">
    <foo>This should be copied</foo>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uefnx/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the innerHTML wrapped by the directive like this

```
var text = element.$$element.context.innerHTML;
```